# R2DBC - Is there a way to use two different database clients when using a CrudRepository?

Tags: spring, kotlin, r2dbc

Fairly new to Java, Spring and R2DBC.

I am using spring and R2DBC to create to database clients using the properties from my config.

I have a ReactiveCrudRepository that I want to use to make queries to the database, but my application keeps throwing an error

Is this possible to do? If not, what is the best approach?

Comment: Tbh... (probably not the answer you're looking for :) lol), but I'd avoid r2dbc... it sucks. If your mapping is any more complex then a simple flat table or 1:1 relationship, you'll need to write all the mapping code manually. Heaven forbid you try to do a 1:M mapping, then you can't even use the row converter hook because you wouldn't be able to batch rows and you end up having to write pretty much ALL the db client code yourself. You can't use Hibernate or Hibernate mappings.

Comment: There is a Hibernate Reactive, but it only works with vert.x drivers, so you need to hack half your code to Spring and the other half to vert.x and map between two completely different interfaces ... and this is coming from a Webflux fan boy :). If you were using a doc store like Mongo or Elastic, I'd say Webflux all day long. I went down the Webflux/MySql rabbit hole and r2dbc is soooo primitive ... I ended up ditching it for WebMvc and QueryDSL.

Comment: P.S. if you INSIST on going down the route you are going (although you'll live to regret it, trust me) ... you basically create an R2dbcEntityOperations bean for each DatabaseClient in your @EnableR2dbcRepositories annotation, you point entityOperationsRef to that bean.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SledgeHammer. Good to know the challenges with R2DBC. In my case though, I am accessing a flat structure. 

Going down the path of using EnableR2dbcRepositories, would I need to qualify each CrudRepository? I’m not clear on how that part would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, you'd have:

DataSource1Configuration.java:

```
@EnableR2dbcRepositories(
    basePackages = {"<namespace of repo1>"},
    entityOperationsRef = "dataSource1EntityOperations")
```

Then:

```
  @Bean
  public R2dbcEntityOperations dataSource1EntityOperations(ConnectionFactory datasource1ConnectionFactory) {
DatabaseClient databaseClient =
    DatabaseClient.builder().connectionFactory(datasource1ConnectionFactory).build();

// rest of creation logic
}
```

How you create the R2dbcEntityOperations bean really depends on what database you're using, how you're getting the connection factory and so on ... mine is vastly different from what you would do since I was building up a lot of custom functionality.

And then do a similiar configuration for DataSource2Configuration.java.